# Desfazendo um pull no Git

Tags: git, versionamento

Estou com um projeto e no momento estou com 3 branches, o `master`, um `dev` e um que precisei criar em paralelo ao dev para uma `funcionalidade` a parte, até ai sem novidades, o meu problema foi que estou no *branch* dev e fiz um `git pull origin funcionalidade` e com isso baixou tudo do funcionalidade para o dev fazendo o *merge*, e não era para ter feito isso, tem como desfazer esse `pull`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Tentou resetar? Tente:

```
git reset --hard
```

Se precisar resetar para um estado específico basta dizer qual é:

```
git reset --hard hash_do_commit_aqui
```

Isto deve funcionar também em algumas situações:

```
git merge --abort
```

Ou ainda:

```
git reset --merge
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Simples soluções para simples problemas! O `git reset --hard` somente não funcionou, pois para a funcionalidade eu já tinha feito alguns commits, dai só procurei o ponto, achei a hash especifica e com isso sim funcionou.

Comment: Uma tática simples que eu uso às vezes é `git reset --hard HEAD~N`, onde `N` é o número de commits pra trás que eu quero voltar.